# How can I write a custom MDM Agent for a Windows 10 Mobile?

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10, windows-10-universal, mdm, windows-10-mobile

I know that a MDM Client is an integral part of Windows 10 and hence it is available on any device running windows 10.The following link explains MDM on Windows 10 in great detail and depth:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/manage/windows-10-mobile-and-mdm

However, I am curious to know(and code) that is it possible to write a **custom MDM Client** for Windows 10 Mobile/Desktop/Device and how.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible, simply because there are no MDM APIs exposed by the OS.
You could write an app that talks to your server and executes commands in sequence, which would mimic the base flow of an MDM protocol. However, the app will be very limited in terms of what it can actually achieve. E.g. you won't be able to install apps, configure accounts, etc.

You could install certificates, although i am not sure those will be system-wide available, and get the basic device info (network hw addresses, battery level etc).